# What's a good, threadsafe, way to pass error strings back from a C shared library

Tags: c++, c, shared-libraries

I'm writing a C shared library for internal use (I'll be dlopen()'ing it to a c++ application, if that matters). The shared library loads (amongst other things) some java code through a JNI module, which means all manners of nightmare error modes can come out of the JVM that I need to handle intelligently in the application. Additionally, this library needs to be re-entrant. Is there in idiom for passing error strings back in this case, or am I stuck mapping errors to integers and using printfs to debug things?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My approach to the problem would be a little different from everyone else's.  They're not wrong, it's just that I've had to wrestle with a different aspect of this problem.

1. A C API needs to provide numeric error codes, so that the code using the API can take sensible measures to recover from errors when appropriate, and pass them along when not.  The `errno.h` codes demonstrate a good categorization of errors; in fact, if you can reuse those codes (or just pass them along, e.g. if all your errors come ultimately from system calls), do so.

   - Do *not* copy `errno` itself.  If possible, return error codes directly from functions that can fail.  If that is not possible, have a `GetLastError()` method on your state object.  You have a state object, yes?
2. If you have to invent your own codes (the `errno.h` codes don't cut it), provide a function analogous to `strerror`, that converts these codes to human-readable strings.

   - It may or may not be appropriate to translate these strings.  If they're meant to be read only by developers, don't bother.  But if you need to show them to the end user, then yeah, you need to translate them.
   - The untranslated version of these strings should indeed be just string constants, so you have no allocation headaches.  However, do not waste time and effort coding your own translation infrastructure.  Use [GNU gettext](http://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/).
3. If your code is layered on top of another piece of code, it is *vital* that you provide direct access to all the error information and relevant context information that that code produces, and you make it easy for developers against your code to wrap up all that information in an error message for the end user.

   - For instance, if your library produces error codes of its own devising as a direct consequence of failing system calls, your state object needs methods that return the `errno` value observed immediately after the system call that failed, the name of the file involved (if any), and ideally also the name of the system call itself.  People get this wrong waaay too often -- for instance, SQLite, otherwise a well designed API, does not expose the `errno` value or the name of the file, which makes it infuriatingly hard to distinguish "the file permissions on the database are wrong" from "you have a bug in your code".

**EDIT:** Addendum: common mistakes in this area include:

- Contorting your API (e.g. with use of out-parameters) so that functions that would naturally return some other value can return an error code.
- Not exposing enough detail for callers to be able to produce an error message that allows a knowledgeable human to fix the problem.  (This knowledgeable human may not be the end user.  It may be that your error messages wind up in server log files or crash reports for developers' eyes only.)
- Exposing too many different fine distinctions among errors.  If your callers will never plausibly do different things in response to two different error codes, they should be the same code.
- Providing more than one *success* code.  This is asking for subtle bugs.

Also, think very carefully about which APIs ought to be allowed to fail.  Here are some things that should never fail:

- Read-only data accessors, especially those that return scalar quantities, *most especially* those that return Booleans.
- Destructors, in the most general sense.  (This is a classic mistake in the UNIX kernel API: `close` and `munmap` should not be able to fail.  Thankfully, at least `_exit` can't.)
- There is a strong case that you should immediately call `abort` if `malloc` fails rather than trying to propagate it to your caller.  (This is not true in C++ thanks to exceptions and RAII -- if you are so lucky as to be working on a C++ project that uses both of those properly.)

In closing: for an example of how to do just about everything *wrong*, look no further than [XPCOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XPCOM).

Comment: Regarding _Contorting your API (e.g. with use of out-parameters)_, what's your rationale for this recommendation ? Using a consistent interface for all the functions that may fail seems like a good idea. This is also the preferred idiom used in the new C11 standard (eg `fopen_s`).

Comment: [ERR02-C. Avoid in band error indicators](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/seccode/ERR02-C.+Avoid+in-band+error+indicators)

Comment: @dlapir: The `_s` functions are nonportable Microsoft crap.  They are *not* part of "the new C11 standard" (unless they got crammed in since the last time I looked; however, regardless, nobody other than MS plans to support them).  They mostly duplicate functionality that *already existed* in a more usable form.  And they are, for the most part, excellent examples of precisely what not to do.

Comment: @dlapir: Further, CERT is just plain wrong on this one.  The datum that a function returns should always be the datum that its callers want to know.  Normally, that is *not* an error code, unless the function is called strictly for its side effects.  If you push the *real* result of a function into an out-parameter so that you can have the return value be an error code, then you complicate all callers to that function, which in my experience is the source of more bugs than any of the bad examples at the link you gave.

Comment: @dlapir: Having said all that, it is also my experience that you should be able to structure the vast majority of your code so that the functions that can fail are invoked strictly for their side effects, and the functions that have interesting return values cannot ever fail.  The big exception is functions that allocate resources, like `malloc` and `open`, and in those cases, if I were designing from scratch, I would do exactly what CERT says not to do, i.e. return a negative in-band error code or a positive meaningful success code.  All the alternatives are worse.

Answer (score 2):

You return pointers to `static const char []` objects. This is always the correct way to handle error strings. If you need them localized, you return pointers to read-only memory-mapped localization strings.

Answer (score 1):

In C, if you don't have internationalization (I18N) or localization (L10N) to worry about, then pointers to constant data is a good way to supply error message strings.  However, you often find that the error messages need some supporting information (such as the name of the file that could not be opened), which cannot really be handled by constant data.

With I18N/L10N to worry about, I'd recommend storing the fixed message strings for each language in an appropriately formatted file, and then using [`mmap()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/mmap.html) to 'read' the file into memory before you fork any threads.  The area so mapped should then be treated as read-only (use `PROT_READ` in the call to `mmap()`).

This avoids complicated issues of memory management and avoids memory leaks.

Consider whether to provide a function that can be called to get the latest error.  It can have a prototype such as:

```
int get_error(int errnum, char *buffer, size_t buflen);
```

I'm assuming that the error number is returned by some other function call; the library function then consults any threadsafe memory it has about the current thread and the last error condition returned to that thread, and formats an appropriate error message (possibly truncated) into the given buffer.

With C++, you can return (a reference to) a standard String from the error reporting mechanism; this means you can format the string to include the file name or other dynamic attributes.  The code that collects the information will be responsible for releasing the string, which isn't (shouldn't be) a problem because of the destructors that C++ has.  You might still want to use `mmap()` to load the format strings for the messags.

You do need to be careful about the files you load and, in particular, any strings used as format strings.  (Also, if you are dealing with I18N/L10N, you need to worry about whether to use the '`n$` notation to allow for argument reordering; and you have to worry about different rules for different cultures/languages about the order in which the words of a sentence are presented.)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could use PWideChars, as Windows does. Its thread safe. What you need is that the calling app creates a PwideChar that the Dll will use to set an error. Then, the callling app needs to read that PWideChar and free its memory.

Comment: The OP mentioned `dlopen` (and not `LoadLibrary`).  That means the odds are this isn't a Windows application.

Answer (score 0):

R. has a good answer (use static const char []), but if you are going to have various spoken languages, I like to use an Enum to define the error codes. That is better than some #define of a bunch of names to an int value.

Comment: You should maybe explain *why* it's better.  (There is at least one good reason I know of, but I don't know if it's the one you're thinking of.)

Answer (score 0):

- return integers, don't set some global variable (like `errno`— even if it is potentially TLSed by an implementation); aking to Linux kernel's style of `return -ENOENT;`.
- have a function similar to `strerror` that takes such an integer and returns a pointer to a const string. This function can transparently do I18N if needed, too, as gettext-returnable strings also remain constant over the lifetime of the translation database.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to provide non-static error messages, then I recommend returning strings like this: error_code_t function(, char** err_msg). Then provide a function to free the error message: void free_error_message(char* err_msg). This way you hide how the error strings are allocated and freed. This is of course only worth implementing of your error strings are dynamic in nature, meaning that they convey more than just a translation of error codes.

Please havy oversight with mu formatting. I'm writing this on a cell phone...